# Navigate to another page on successful Razorpay payment

Tags: reactjs, next.js, razorpay

I have a checkout page where I want to navigate to Home Page once the payment is successful. Currently, I have used this code for navigating to home page but it's not navigating as expected.

```
data = await createOrder(); //Calls the backend route for creating order.
    console.log("DATA");
    console.log(data);
    const res = loadScript("https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js");
    if (!data) {
      toast.error("Please check if you are online");
      return;
    }
    if (!res) {
      toast.error("Razorpay failed to load");
      return;
    } else {
      const options = {
        key: <RAZORPAY_KEY>,
        amount: price,
        currency: "INR",
        name: "Merchant",
        description: "Complete Transaction",
        order_id: data.order_id,
        prefill: {
          name: checkout.name,
          email: checkout.email,
          contact: checkout.phone,
        },
      };

      const rzp = new Razorpay(options);
      rzp.on("payment.captured", (_) => {
        toast.success("Order Placed Successfully");
        cart[1]([]);
        router.push("/");
      });
      rzp.open();
```

The Razorpay key being used here is a test key and I am not sure whether this is the reason for the code not working.

Comment: You can pass `callback_url` in the options when creating Razorpay instance. But your code should work, can you post a codesandbox link ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the *callback_url* property in **options** :

```
const options= {
 // code
 callback_url: '/home'
}
```